# Do scans at a chosen DPI resolution have all the same file size?

Tags: scanner, scanning

If I scan a batch of documents, all the same format — not the same content — at same DPI value, will each page take the same amount of bytes?

Comment: In which image type (JPEG, PNG, ...)? Is the size of the scanned area the same for each page?

Comment: @stickybit I [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1591060/167207), but reading the question again this *might* be a homework question of some kind. I mean it reads like one. But honestly it seems like a fair question to be regarding what many people in the 21st century might know — or not know — about compressed versus uncompressed images and DPI.

Answer (score 2):

## DPI will not ever consistently result in files of the same size in a compressed file.

### But it will result in similarly sized file in an uncompressed format.

> “If I scan a batch of documents, all the same format — not the same content — at same DPI value, will each page take the same amount of bytes?”

Nope. The key is “…not the same content…” since the content of image is the initial determiner of file size. Given a standard white background and standard width and height, a scanned document with one word in it will be of less of a file size than one with more words and even images.

DPI is simply a measurement of dots per inch. Dots represent data. More data, more dots and the more data again. And the file size past that would be determined by the chosen image format and the compression level set which is what most scanners output.

But if — for example — you created an uncompressed TIFF of the same two documents, then the file size would be as close to the same as possible between the two documents.

That is because in an uncompressed image format, the scan is like a big piece of graph paper where each box (aka: pixel) needs to be accounted for. A compressed image format would be able to compress — in the file or visually — the related image data.